# How to set deadline for URL Fetch in Google App Engine (PHP)?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, url, fetch, deadlines

URL Fetch overview says:

You can set a deadline for a request, the most amount of time the 
service will wait for a response. By default, the deadline for a fetch 
is 5 seconds. The maximum deadline is 60 seconds for HTTP requests and 
10 minutes for task queue and cron job requests.

Now, how can i set deadline to 60-sec?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your asking for a PHP app.

Set the deadline in the http context, per [this](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) documentation.

```
$options = ["http" => ["timeout" => 60]];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$data = file_get_contents("http://foo.bar", false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter deadline=60. See [the fetch documentation here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$context =
    array("http"=>
      array(
        "timeout" => 60
      )
    );
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$result = file_get_contents("http://example.com", false, $contex);
```